# How to set Matlab jupyter kernel backend to gui?

Tags: matlab, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How can I set matlab_kernel's figure backend to Matlab's normal gui for plotting? Preferably I'd like to add a line into a jupyter config profile. Thanks!

Comment: In general, kernels have their own configuration systems; Jupyter doesn't provide a common config system for kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just modified the source code to get the result I want